# Express server not exiting process and re-freeing port

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, process, nodemon

I have an express server in a node app.  I need to be able to run this node app with the debugger.  I also need to be able to stop and restart the server easily without binding up the port it runs on.  I need to tap into the shutdown to do some cleanup, which I do like this:

```js
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port whatever");
});

process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    server.close(() => {
        console.log(chalk.blue('Shutting down server'));
        // some cleanup code
        process.exit();
    });
});
```

My start script uses nodemon to restart on save.  Here are the relevant parts of my package.json related to that:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "start:debug": "node --inspect -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register ./src/server.ts",
        "start": "nodemon",
    },
    "nodemonConfig": {
        "ignore": [...],
        "watch": ["src"],
        "exec": "npm run start:debug",
        "ext": "ts"
    },
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Node: Nodemon",
            "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
            "restart": true,
            "protocol": "inspector"
        }
    ]
}
```

This seems to work.  It starts properly, is accessible through the node debugger, and restarts on save using nodemon. When I hit `ctrl + c`, the server shuts down and logs `"Shutting down server"`.  However, even after that get's logged, node logs `Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...`.  When I hit `ctrl + c` again and rerun `npm start`, I get a crash saying `Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::PORT#`.

What's going wrong here?  My server *seems* to be shutting down gracefully, but the debugger seems to *not* shut down successfully, and there's a node process still hogging that port.  Its getting difficult to start and stop my server cleanly and debug issues.

Comment: Have you stopped or detached your debug client?  It sounds like maybe it's still handing onto something and thus the debug server hasn't been shut-down yet?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, whether manually or programatically.  Any ideas for me?

Comment: What are you using for a debugger?

Comment: I'm using chrome's node debugger

Comment: Then, you close the tab that you were running the debugger in.  That will disconnect the debugger.

Comment: My goodness.  So simple.  I looked into node-inspector-manager (NiM), which is a lot better than the node debugger tool I was using.  It can be configured to automatically connect and open a chrome window to the debugger when you start the app, and automatically disconnect and close the debugger window when the app shuts down.  Brilliant.  If you want to put your comments in an answer so I can mark it as the answer, please do.

Comment: Yes, I use NiM also.  It is helpful.  I wrote an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the debugger to disconnect, you need to close the Chrome tab that has the debugger connection in it.  That will allow the previous instance of your app to fully exit.